# A design pattern to decide what SQL query to choose

Tags: c#, database, design-patterns, connection-string, oledb

I am developing a Winforms application that contains a connection string to connect to a SQL Server database and say I have 15 different queries that I need to run throughout my program called `query1, query2, ...query15`.

I would like to extend my program's abilities so that the user can also use other database types such as Oracle, MySql and Sqlite. That means there will be different versions of my 15 queries for each type.

I want to collect all my query scripts in one place so my calling methods can just refer to them by names e.g. `InsertNewCustomer(string name)` and then my pattern - looking at the type of connection I have set inside my program will run the corresponding method.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: @KenWhite yes the configuration file currently does contain the connection string. But what happens to the queries? An `Sql Server` insert is different from  a `MySql` insert. I am looking for a query to make that decision for me.

Comment: Yes, I misread your question (not sure how, now that I read it again). I removed my comment to clean up. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do a **Factory** and **Strategy** pattern. What it does is that the Factory holds all the instances/type of your strategies (*in this case your database types*).

Here is a mock code for you to get you started at.

```
public class DatabaseStrategyFactory
{
    private static DatabaseStrategyFactory _instance;
    private Dictionary<string, Strategy> _collection;

    private DatabaseStrategyFactory()
    {

    }

    // singleton pattern
    public static DatabaseStrategyFactory Instance { get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new DatabaseStrategyFactory()); }}

    public static Initialize()
    {
        // load all strategies either by creating instances or storing the type
        if(_collection == null)
        {
            _collection = new Dictionary<string, Strategy>();
            _collection.Add(*string key either by class name/enum or whatever you want*, instance or type);
        }
    }

    public Strategy GetStrategy(string name)
    {
        if(_collection == null)
            throw new Exception();
        Strategy strategy = null;
        _collection.TryGetValue(name, out strategy);
        return strategy;
    }
}
```

read more for [Factory](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) and [Strategy](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html);

Comment: Could you please dumb it down to be a bit more specific to my case?

Comment: With the factory, it could hold all the instances of your type right? If your sql query is static or not changing, the instance could have a private field of string that has the query. So by that, you could have multiple classes with specific queries that is being used only on that class. Let me know if you need more expounding.

Comment: Also, you can alter it and not do a singleton approach if you have IOC containers, that way i'td be more testable.